# Procurve 2810 command line - reassigning ports to a different VLAN

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve

A very basic question, but my googling has failed to find an answer...

At present the VLAN config looks like this:

```
vlan 1  
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"  
   untagged 1  
   ip address 10.200.1.134 255.255.255.0
   tagged 2,Trk1
   no untagged 3-20,23-24
   exit
vlan 2
   name "VLAN2"
   no ip address
   tagged Trk1
   exit
vlan 4
   name "VLAN4"
   no ip address
   tagged Trk1
   exit
vlan 3
   name "VLAN3"
   untagged 3-20,23-24
   no ip address
   tagged 2,Trk1
   exit
```

What I would like to do is move ports 23-24 out of VLAN3 and into VLAN2, but I am unfamiliar with the Provurve CLI syntax (beyond the "show config" command obviously!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `menu` command and running through the menu system is the easiest for beginners.

From the main menu (">" means <kbd>enter</kbd>):
2. Switch Configuration > 8. VLAN > 3. VLAN Port Assignment > Edit >
Find the port and vLan, <kbd>space</kbd> until it reads as you want.
> to finish, Save >

To do it through the CLI:

```
conf t
vlan 2
untag 23-24
wr m
```

The last line saves the configuration to flash (otherwise configuration changes are only saved to RAM (allowing you to easily recover from messed up configuration with a quick power cycle).

Note: since a port can only be assigned to one vlan in untagged mode, when you assign them to vlan2, they'll be automatically removed from 3. For assignments in tagged mode this would not be true. Also you can't actually remove untagged assignments because ports always have to be assigned to some vlan.